# How to use excel VBA/macros to populate array formulas in a grid (using multiple criteria)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to code a macro that will format data into a grid using multiple criteria. Below is an example of what the raw data would look like (stack overflow wouldnt let me upload a picture for some reason):

**Chart 1 (raw data)**

| Country | Color | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Red | 25 |
| USA | White | 50 |
| UK | Blue | 75 |
| Japan | Red | 100 |

Now this is the grid I would like to data to display in. This is something that would be repeated every day in a new worksheet and the data might change so a formula is needed.

**Chart 2 (what I want)**

|  | USA | UK | Japan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 25 |  | 100 |
| White | 50 |  |  |
| Blue |  | 75 |  |

Basically I just need the Balance numbers in Chart 1 to appear in a grid using Country and Color as criteria as seen in Chart 2. So far I have tried using an index match array formula using "Color" and "Country" as the criteria, but it is not working. This is the VBA code i currently have (balRange refers to Chart 1 and the formula array is connected to Chart 2):

```
Dim balRange As String
balRange = "A2:C5"

Range(balRange).Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=(INDEX('Chart 1'!R2C3:R5C3,MATCH(1,(R1C = 'Chart 1'!R2C1:R5C1)*(RC1 = 'Chart 1'!R2C2:R5C2),0)))"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA using `XLOOKUP` and dynamic arrays assuming your version of Excel supports them. In Chart2!B2, enter `=XLOOKUP(B1:D1&A2:A4,Chart1!A2:A5&Chart1!B2:B5,Chart1!C2:C5),"")`.  The results will spill into the other cells.

[More on XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)
[More on Dynamic Arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)